# some details about using ueye_cam to drive my 1221LE-C camera

Tags: ros, ueye-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, it's my first time to use programs on ROS. I have tried to understand it, but it need more time.

I followed the build instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam, but I have no idea about how to do next. All I need is to get camera_topic and camera_info i.e. the two topics in Published Topics. But I don't know how. So, could anyone tell me how to run to get the two topics.

There is no problems in building, and I use ROS indigo on Ubuntu14.4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199936/some-details-about-using-ueye_cam-to-drive-my-1221le-c-camera/) by [QichaoXu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21207/qichaoxu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To inspect the data coming from camera topic / camera_info in terminal:

1. rostopic echo /camera/image_raw (WARNING: possibly will generate a lot of raw ASCII)
2. rostopic echo /camera/camera_info

To visualize the data from camera: rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw

To subscribe to the camera:
http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0